# Merging project.pbxproj with conflicts

Tags: xcode, mercurial, merge

My project has three branches, default, release1 and release2. Default is where I develop all features, release1 and release2 include the features from default plus things that each branch needs but the other cannot possibly have.

I have no problems merging my code but all breaks down when I need to manage conflicts in project.pbxproj. The file format is opaque and what means is that I end up having no clue on what's going on. The most common end result is Xcode refusing to load the project.

How do you manage this? Is project.pbxproj documented anywhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common problem.  I try very hard make sure that our team coordinates before making any changes to the project file.  When we have a merge conflict, if it's not obvious hwo to fix is using a diff tool, I usually just choose one of the project files over the other one, and then open the project in Xcode to redo the appropriate changes.